# sudo apt-get update error

Tags: apt

I am getting following errors repeatedly upon using `apt-get update` command :

```
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg                      
  Something wicked happened resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

**My `ifconfig -a`**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3c:ec:b2  
          inet addr:10.169.106.83  Bcast:10.169.107.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a461:6091:3581:5c28/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35003 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:33508 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3989394 (3.8 MiB)  TX bytes:29154542 (27.8 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:30157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:29171892 (27.8 MiB)  TX bytes:29171892 (27.8 MiB)
```

**My `route -n`**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.169.104.1    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.169.104.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

**My `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`**

```
 #interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

 #Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
 #For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

 #Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
```

**My `sudo nano /etc/sources.list`** is empty

**My `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`**

```
# Generated by resolvconf
domain cob.apac.bosch.com
nameserver 10.47.194.125
nameserver 10.47.194.62
nameserver 10.47.32.125
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I also could not access my internet through raspbian browser

Comment: can you ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org or even google.com? if neither of those work but ping 216.58.198.238 does then its the DNS. That IP address is what I get for pinging google.com. Google's free DNS servers are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

Your domain name `cob.apac.bosch.com` makes me almost certain you're behind a corporate firewall with no internet access, which is the reason for the errors you're seeing.